Detect linearly dependent columns from a full-row rank matrix.
Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, with $m\leq n$, be a full-row-rank matrix. Then, there exist a collection of $n-m$ columns in $A$ that are linearly dependent on the other columns. What is the most computationally-efficient method to find a set of indeces of $n-m$ linearly dependent columns? I know that I may apply some standard decomposition algorithms, such as QR-factorisation to $A^T$, or SVD to $A$, etc. However, the information I am looking for may require less computational effort.

That's false. Take $n = m+1$. If $A$ has no 0 column, then any set of 1 column is independent.

It is correct what you say, but I meant another concept: in that case, there must be, at least, one column that can be expressed as linear combination of the other m columns of A. As such, that column can be removed from my matrix, because I want to make it square. This is my final goal.
BTW, thanks for your comment, I have amended my question :)

Gaussian elimination is fairly computationally efficient, no?

Yes, determining an echelon form suffices, as the pivot columns specify a basis for the column space, so the remaining columns are redundant.
